# How to Add in items in a column using Flexbox and Material UI

Tags: css, material-ui

I am looking for some advice as I can't seem to get these items positioned on the modal. I am looking to get add the item counter as text and stars underneath. With the unassigned text at the bottom. I have tried many layouts. This is my code so far:

```
 const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 3),
  },
  paper: {
    maxWidth: 800,
    margin: `${theme.spacing(2)}px auto`,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200,
  },
    playButton: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      "& .rating": {
        flex: 1
    },
  }
});

function Tasks(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
            <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs>
              <div className="name-label">
              Name
              </div>
              <Typography variant="h6">
              Order cofee beans
              </Typography>
              <div className="form-divider"></div>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                  Process of Description
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item classes={{ root: props.classes.playButton}}>
      <Grid item xs={3} className="playButton">
        <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>
      </Grid>
      <div className="workers-assigned-label">
      Workers Assigned
    </div>
    <div>
      count / total
    </div>
    <div className="rating">
      Stars go here
    </div>
    <div>
      unassigned
    </div>
    </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Tasks);
```

I have added an image of a screenshot of the design so that it is clear what I am trying to achieve.

Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5freH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want something like this, where the `flex: 1` is whatever you want to be stretching and taking up any extra space.

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  playButton: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "relative",
    "& .playButton": {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "80%",
      left: "-55px",
      transform: "translateY(-50%)",
    },
    "& .rating": {
      flex: 1
    }
  }
});

const YourComponent = props => (
  {...}
  <Grid item classes={{ root: props.classes.playButton}}>
    <Grid item xs={3} className="playButton">
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </Grid>
    <div className="workers-assigned-label">
      Workers Assigned
    </div>
    <div>
      count / total
    </div>
    <div className="rating">
      stars go here
    </div>
    <div>
      unassigned
    </div>
  </Grid>
  {...}
);
```

I suggest you checkout [this resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to see what you can do with flex.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell where you're stuck at without an updated code base. If you have a Pen I might be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks that has aligned them. I now have an issue where the play button is not aligned with them, do you know how I would get that back into the centre?

Comment: You didn't add the .playButton style.

Comment: How do you mean sorry?

Comment: Take a careful look at the playButton style, you forgot to include position: relative and the whole "& .playButton".

Comment: I see. Thank you.